# AMD USB error almost bricked my ext SSD, main SSD has an ESD folder written into it now. Should I be worried about the drives?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, amd-ryzen

For context: https://www.extremetech.com/computing/320181-amd-investigating-usb-issues-in-500-series-motherboards

So I tried plugging my keyboard into a unused USB port on my desktop, and somehow that led to a massive power surge that bricked my connected external SSD, and shut off my computer.

When i did get it to reboot, the external SSD was completely wiped, renamed to `ESD_USB` and i needed to re-extend the unused partition back on it and rename it.

Fair enough. Still, my main OS drive (NVME m.2) is what I'm terribly worried about here as I have loads of code not yet backed up to the cloud. I opened it up and saw two folders that werent there before:

```
1) $WINDOWS.~BT
2) ESD
```

So far the main C: drive (abovementioned NVME drive with two mysterious folders inside) works 'fine', disk check using crystalDiskInfo shows GOOD disk health.

Would like to seek some insight into what's going on here. Is this a mobo issue or related to the famous AMD 5000 series USB bug?

Comment: _"I have loads of code not yet backed up"_ - don't wait then. Your hardware has been kind enough to give you a warning. Fix your backup strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Those two folders are completely fine and belong to Windows:

- `C:\ESD` is a copy of the Windows installation image used for recovery (with BIOS installations only, I think).
- `C:\Windows.~BT` is a temporary folder Windows upgrades use to store temporary files used when upgrading to the next major Windows release, e.g. Windows 10 20H2.

As for the external drive, two things:

- Terminology note: **Bricked** refers to a piece of hardware completely breaking, i.e. no longer working the way it should, it's just like an actual brick. If your drive is still working as a drive, it's not "bricked".
- Considering the name "ESD_USB" and the temporary Windows upgrade folder... Are you sure you didn't misclick during an Upgrade for Windows using the Media Creation Tool (or in Windows's Troubleshooting section of the Settings) unintentionally trying to make your external drive into a bootable recovery drive?

As for the AMD issue, I don't think it's related to your computer:

- These USB problems seem to make USB ports stop working randomly. They won't turn off your computer.
- Your computer shouldn't turn off randomly just from plugging in an USB device. USB ports are specifically isolated/protected by standards. Even if you short out pins within the USB port all that should happen is the individual port turning off. The PC should keep running.
- *If your PC turned off from you touching a random part of it's casing with your skin or a cable, this might indicate some significant wiring or isolation issue and a potential health hazard** (or at least a potential danger to your hardware components). If you can, let someone knowledgeable have a look or at least try changing the outlet used, in case it's not properly grounded (assuming this is not a laptop connected without grounding).